# Hide nav content when Magnific-popup is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I would like to know if it is possible to hide  html content when a popup is shown. (I am using Magnific-popup). I have a button that calls this popup to be shown.  And of course, when popup is closed nav content will be displayed again.

Nav code to hide and display

```
<nav class="top-nav">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="">A link</a></li>
   <li><a href="">A link</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

button that calls popup

```
<a href="#register-popup" class="open-popup-link">Call popup</span></a>
```

Popup code

```
<div id="register-popup" class="white-popup mfp-hide">
  <div class="container">
    <p>some content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you very very much for your help :)

Comment: There is a CSS solution to this problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

You can hide the top-nav via the open callback of the Magnific plugin. You can also use the close callback to show it again.

```
    $('#register-popup').magnificPopup({
        callbacks: {
            open: function() {
                $('.top-nav').hide();
            }
            close: function() {
                $('.top-nav').show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Magnific-popup accepts callback on open and close events.

```
$('.selector').magnificPopup({
  // you may add other options here, e.g.:
  preloader: true,

  callbacks: {
    open: function() {
      // Will fire when this exact popup is opened
      // this - is Magnific Popup object
      $('.top-nav').hide();
    },
    close: function() {
      // Will fire when popup is closed
      $('.top-nav').show();
    }
    // e.t.c.
  }
});
```

For more information en Magnific-popup, checkout there API documentation:

http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html

Answer (score 0):

```
  you can use those API methodes :

 $('#register-popup').magnificPopup({
  // you may add other options here, e.g.:
  preloader: true,

  callbacks: {
  open: function() {
  // Will fire when this exact popup is opened

},
close: function() {
  // Will fire when popup is closed
  }
  // e.t.c.
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When the Magnific Popup is active, the class .mfp-zoom-out-cur is added to the body. If you want to hide anything use that class to target whatever you want to hide in the layout. No additional JavaScript necessary.

```
.mfp-zoom-out-cur .top-nav {
    display:none;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```